Bound the spectral norm of the precision matrix using column-wise norm
In this paper, the authors obtain the convergence rate of the precision matrix concerning the spectral norm, (Theorem 1, page 7)
$$
\|\hat{\Omega}-\Omega\|_2 \le CM_p s_p\sqrt{\frac{\log p}{n}}
$$
where $\|\Omega\|_{L1}=\underset{1\le j\le p}{\max}\sum_{i=1}^{p}|\omega_{ij}|\le M_p$ and $\underset{1\le j\le p}{\max}\sum_{i=1}^{p}1\left(\omega_{ij}\neq 0\right)\le s_p$.
They prove this theorem by controlling the columns of the precision matrix (page 37, inequality(9)):
$$
|\hat{\beta}_{S_i}-\omega_{S_i}|\le C\sqrt{\frac{\log p}{n}}
$$
where $\hat{\beta}_i$ is the ith column of $\hat{\Omega}$.
How could we control the convergence rate using the column-wise bound? Thanks a lot!
